# Is there a way to validate related documents in mongoose that is more efficient than .populate() and aggregate it together

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

Given these models:

Products:

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    price: Number,
    steps: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'steps'
    }]
});
```

Steps:

```
const stepSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    minimum: Number,
    maximum: Number,
    items: [
        {
            name: String,
            price: Number
        }
    ]
});
```

Is there a better way to query an object that has N number of Products and not all products.steps selected without using .populate() (because it will make a request for each value inside the products.steps array) and a for loop to sum all prices included in productSchema and stepSchema?

Exemple of use:

On my documents I've got product collection like this:

```
[{
    id: 1
    name: Pizza,
    description: "Medium (3 flavors)",
    price: 10,
    steps: [{
        "1",
        "2"

    }]
},
{
    id: 2
    name: Pizza,
    description: "small (1 flavors)",
    price: 10,
    steps: [{
        "1",

    }]
}]
```

And steps like:

```
[{
    id: 1
    name: "Flavor",
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 1,
    items: [
        {
            id: 1
            name: "mozzarella",
            price: 4
        },
        {
            id: 2
            name: "pepperoni",
            price: 5
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2
    name: "Border",
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 0,
    items: [
        {
            id: 3
            name: "With normal cheese",
            price: 0
        },
        {
            id: 4
            name: "With special cheese",
            price: 3
        }
    ]
}]
```

So is there a better way to validade an object like this in my BD with less query and without a for loop?

```
products: [
    {
        productId: 1,
        price: 30,
        quantity: 3,
        steps: [{
            stepId: 1
            items: [
                {
                    itemId: 1,
                    price: 4
                },
                {
                    itemId: 2,
                    price: 5
                }
            ]
        }]

    }
]
```

Comment: could you please elaborate, what you mean by validate. Also, please explain the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think below steps should be followed:

1. [$lookup(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) or populate
2. [$project(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: I've looked up into this aggregations frameworks, but my problems is the O(log n) in number of request on the database.